# Is there a way to use mysql client binary tool without installing to connect to another mysql server?

Tags: mysql, client

Here is the situation, I have access to some servers and don't have the root privilege to install mysql-client using 'yum', so I'm wondering maybe I can find some binary tool downloaded directly from internet to connect to another mysql server. I googled it, but failed. Does anybody know where I can find such thing? or some other solutions to my question?

Comment: Create an aws ec2 linux instance where you do have the rights.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The standard `mysql` client command line utility can be used in any Linux machine to connect to a MySQL Server anywhere if you have connectivity to TCP port 3306.

From http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mysql/, download MySQL Server, Linux, Generic, 64 bit (or 32 bit) TAR Archive.  Un-tar it, and look for the program file called `mysql` in the directory `bin/`.  That's the command line client.  It doesn't need to be installed, just copy that file into your oath or run it from the current direcrory.

Comment: some so is not found display by `ldd mysql` running on debian:10